# elisp mapcar + lambda + defmacro help

Tags: emacs, macros, lisp, elisp

I am trying to generate functions using a macro:

```
(defmacro make-my-emacs-command-region (cmd name)
  (list 'defun (intern (format "my-emacs-command-%s-%s" cmd name))
        '(&optional arg)
        (list 'interactive "p")
        (list (intern (format "mark-%s" name)) 'arg)
        (list (intern (format "my-emacs-command-%s-region" cmd))
              '(region-beginning) '(region-end))))
```

generator:

```
(mapcar (lambda (a) (make-my-emacs-command-region a buffer))
        '(foo bar))
```

But I get:

```
my-emacs-command-a-buffer
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I force to pass value of `a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My elisp is a bit rusty, but until someone comes up with the actual explanation:  I could get your examples to work a bit more as expected my replacing `cmd` with `(eval cmd)` (possibly same with `name`) in the macro definition body.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

A major point of lisp macros is that the arguments are ***not*** evaluated.  Read up on the [macro pages in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Macros.html#Macros), specifically the [expansion of macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Expansion.html#Expansion).  The `macroexpand` function would be of use in debugging the problem.  Also, [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote) might help you write the body of the macro a little more succinctly.